# Can an Ethereum address hold more than Ether?

Tags: addresses, tokens

Let me explain it with examples. On Bitcoin protocol, for example, you have Counterparty. As it uses embedded consensus, every XCP address is linked to a Bitcoin address. So if you hold bitcoins on that address, you can also hold XCP on that address and even more tokens (such as Storj).

Is something like that possible on Ethereum ? I mean, can you hold other tokens than Ethers on your address ? Can you even hold coins from other blockchains on an Ethereum address (for example, Bitcoin, Litecoin, etc.) ?

Answer (score 4):

Of course yes. That's how The DAO tokens were stored. Technically you have a data field on each transaction. It's up to you to use it to hold another token transaction or whatever you need.

EDIT: There is now, for some times now infact, a standard way to implement tokens on Ethereum and it's described by [ERC20](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard). So you can rely on this standard and your token will be easy to manage from any ERC20 compliant wallet and even integrate easier on exchanges.

Comment: My concern is more about holding coins from other blockchains than Ethereum. For example, can you BTC on your ETH address ? LTC ?

Comment: can you hold BTC* sorry

Comment: No. You can only hold tokens based on the same protocol. This is the same with BTC. You can't hold ETH on a BTC address either. But you should modify your question as you give the example of BTC tokens like EXP that are just using same protocol as BTC exactly like DAO on Ethereum. You probably misunderstood BTC too.

Comment: You can use the same private key that you use for ETH to store BTC. I'm not sure why you'd want to do that, but you could. However, it will produce a different address, as bitcoin uses a different series of steps to make an address.

Comment: Then, is that possible for a smart-contract to interact with another blockchain coins ? Let's say the smart-contract has the private and public key of the other blockchain address and then, can move coins ?